# How to make cover page using Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to make a cover page using LibreOffice. But where is the cover option? I can't find it out.

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1**

You can format the page as the First Page

When it is formatted as the first page, You can add some features.

`Format` > `Page` > `Organizer`>`Next Style` and select `First Page`

**Method 2**

You can edit it on the template called ***Master Document*** template.

With master document template, you can create the document ***as a Book***.

So you can have Cover pages, Index pages, Preface pages etc.

You can download the master Document template from [libreoffice.org](http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center/a-master-document-template/pscreleasefolder.2012-02-04.3211779045/1.0/templatemd.zip) as a .zip file.

You need to extracted .zip file.

Command : `unzip [ZIP FILE] -d [DESTINATION FOLDER]`

Then you need to open the template `.odm`file with Libre Office.

Answer (score 4):

I may be using a different version to user224082

Format > Title page

add the number of title pages you want.
ensure Style is "First Page"

Answer (score -7):

Try this Google search: ... [Google Search Listing](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Libre%20Office%20cover%20page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=84jBUorDJIa6yQH39oHoDw)

Here are a couple of links to try: ... [A detailed PDF of how to make cover pages](http://files.yajhfc.de/doc/Creating_PDF_coverpages.pdf)

....................................................................... [Short Video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxqvxHAHj24)

Comment: Suggesting "try on Google" usually doesn't help much. If you've got useful information on the topic, please consider adding the gist of it in the answer and then if necessary link to external resources.